# How to update picklist value dynamically from Custom object?

Tags: trigger, picklist

I have two custom objects **'Object_1__c**' and '**Object_2_*c***', there is a custom field 'Type_c' in 'Object_1__c' which is a Picklist datatype . whenever a new record is submitted in 'Object_2__c' it should populate in Picklist(Object_1_*c.Type*_c) value. i.e Type__c.value should be Object_2__c.name

How to Query a picklist Value ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to populate picklist values in objects names?
You can do this only by using Visual Force picklist.
Of course you can put object name in picklist using trigger, because picklist is just kind of text field.
But you just put there just some string, availble values are still same as before this update.

What you should do is to create VF page (1 if this field is read-only for user - just to show value, and 2 if user should be able to change value - in that case you have to create also VF page for edit)

Here is some example of the code:

```
public class Object1picklistcontroller{

Object__1 obj;

public Object1picklistcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    obj = (object1) controller.getRecord();
}

public SelectOption[] getOptions() {
    SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[] {};

    for (Object__2 obj2 : [SELECT Id,Name FROM Object__2 WHERE Object__1 = : obj.Id]) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(obj2.Id, obj2.Name));
    }
    if (options.isEmpty()) {
        options.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    }
    return options;
  }
}
```

Page picklist

```
<apex:selectList value="{!Obj.Object_2_Id__c}" label="Type" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write an After insert trigger, assuming it is a one to one relationship

```
trigger populatePicklist on Object_2__c(After Insert){

  Map<ID,Object_1__c> obj1 = New Map<ID,Object_1__c>();

  for(Object_2__c obj2 : trigger.new){

     obj1.put(obj2.LOOKUPFIELDTOOBJ1,New Object_1__c(id=obj2.LOOKUPFIELDTOOBJ1, Type__c = obj2.Name);

  }

  if(obj1.isEmpty() == false)
     update obj1.values();


}
```

Comment: just little advice, use if(!obj1.isEmpty())

Comment: Agreed but the ! gets missed when people try to replicate the code. The = false is hard to miss. Curious though if this is just a preference or if there is some performance implications?